# Something that makes you feel better, not when you are sad?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call something that makes you feel good/better, because it is good news or funny. But you were feeling normal before, you weren't sad or anything. But just by seeing that thing you felt better.

Comment: There's an idiom "to get a kick out of something."  I'd say, "I get a kick out of reading Humans of New York every day, because the stories are so heartwarming."

Comment: "After watching /listening [TV program / type of music ] I feel really good." As James Brown once sang : [I feel good / I knew that I would now](https://www.google.it/search?q=I+feel+good&oq=I+feel+good&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=i+feel+good+james+brown)

Answer (score 4):

You can describe something as [**uplifting**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/uplifting) if it inspires happiness or hope. You can also hearten people. 
**[Hearten](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hearten)** - Make more cheerful or confident. 
Such an object would be **heartening**.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *encouraging* would be serviceable,

> [**encouraging**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encouraging) *adjective*: giving hope or promise <*encouraging* news>

(Merriam-Webster *online*)

Comment: Good answer, where did you get that definition from? I used the Oxford dictionary.

Comment: +1 @Yeshe, thank you, but I was a minute or so behind your post so I deleted and went with this alternative. I took *uplift* from Merriam-Webster online.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can receive a **lift** from some pleasant event. Or be lifted by it.

> **verb**
>
> raise (a person's spirits or confidence). "we heard inspiring talks
>   which lifted our spirits"
>
> synonyms: boost, raise, buoy up, elevate, give a lift to, cheer up,
>   perk up, enliven, uplift, brighten up, lighten, ginger up, gladden,
>   encourage, stimulate, arouse, revive, restore; More
>
> **noun**
>
> a feeling of confidence or cheerfulness. "winning this match has given
>   everyone a lift"
>
> synonyms: boost, fillip, pick-me-up, stimulus, impetus, encouragement,
>   spur, reassurance, aid, help, push;
>
> [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=lift%20definition)

Answer (score 0):

A ***[boost](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boost):***

> - An encouraging act or comment.
> - encouragement, improvement, or help: a boost to morale.

- Sammy got a real boost in his confidence when he won his first ever race.
- The little restaurant got a real boost when it received an excellent review in the local newspaper.

(The Free Dictionry)

Answer (score 0):

Your respondents are creating a fine Thesaurus for you. I add "exhilarating".

Answer (score -1):

A **tonic** (*noun*):

1. (Defn. 2) anything invigorating, physically, mentally or morally

> '*His cheerful greeting was a real tonic.*'

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com)

2. (Defn. 2) something that makes you happier or healthier

> '*This holiday has been the perfect tonic for you.*'

Source: